# Get Array in order based on criteria using excel formula

Tags: arrays, excel

Hi I've been struggling how to get the array in order based on criteria, for example here in the table below I would like to get the array of the values in Column B for product "B" in Column A. The output should be {2.03;2.09;1.84} in order.

[image]

Currently here's the available formulas I've found but does not address the ouput I would like to achieve.

```
=IF(A2:A7="B",B2:B7,"")
```

The result is {"";2.03;"",2.09;"";1.84}

Another formula is

```
=SMALL(IF(A2:A7="B",B2:B7),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(A2:A7,"B"))))
```

The result is in ascending {1.84;2.03;2.09}

What I wanted to achieve is to return an array based on order as per occurence, as per example should be {2.03;2.09;1.84}.

Anyone knows the formula for this?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What are you doing with that array, as a cell will only show one value, do you have Office 365, are the results spilling down, are you using that in another formula?

Comment: Hi Scott, I only have Excel 2013. Yes I'm using it another formula (MMULT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the new Dynamic Array Formula FILTER, use:

```
=FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7="B")
```

Put that in the first cell and Excel will spill the results automatically

If not then use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/($A$2:$A$7="B"),ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNTIF(A2:A7,"B")))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013, and it don't have yet this Dynamic Array Formula FILTER. :(

Comment: Thanks Scott. It worked great. Is there a way where let's say I just wanted to get the last two value array for product "B" {2.09;1.84}, as the list add up from time to time and I just wanted to get tha last 2 or 3 values.

Comment: `ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNTIF(A2:A7,"B")-1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNTIF(A2:A7,"B")))`

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. You're a wizard on this. :)